# Check whether an article has any correction or been retracted

Tags: publications, reference-request, website, errors-erratum, retraction

Is there any website where I could enter the reference of an article, and see whether any correction or retraction has been made on the article?

I know some publishers [indicate](http://bjsm.bmj.com/content/34/2/81.short) it on their website, but ideally I would prefer to use the same website to check (i.e. a Google Scholar for corrections/retractions). APIs are good too.

[image]

Comment: In principle you can always ask the author(s).  "I read your article X and found it very interesting.  I want to make sure I have the most recent version..." or something along those lines. Alternatively, if it's published you could try asking an editor (after searching their site for instructions on how to find it yourself).  I gather you are in need of something that specifically avoids the direct approaches, though, but I figured it wouldn't hurt to mention it.

Comment: Check out CrossMark. It is a link placed on the article's PDF which redirects to a web page that tells you whether the document is current or there are new versions. I know that at least some IoP journals use it. Here: http://www.crossref.org/crossmark/

Answer (score 8):

Retraction Watch has recently [announced](http://retractionwatch.com/2015/11/24/new-partnership-will-create-retraction-database/) a collaboration with  The Center For Open Science (COS) to create a free, comprehensive database of retractions.

> Together, COS and CSI will develop the technical infrastructure needed to support existing and new Retraction Watch content on the OSF. Further, COS will enhance discoverability and brand awareness by integrating this content into the SHARE Notify (http://osf.io/share) system, a searchable database of over 3 million research-related events, and by associating Retraction Watch content with related article DOIs when possible. With the technical support of COS, CSI can focus on delivering new content and developing new audiences that can make more informed decisions based on accurate research outputs.

It sounds like this database would allow you to search for articles by DOI and get retraction-related events.

(The database appears to already track retractions from PubMed Central; presumably Retraction Watch would be added as another data source.)

---

Update (2018-11-06 by [shamisen](https://academia.stackexchange.com/users/12627/shamisen)): Retraction Watch launched its database: http://retractiondatabase.org/RetractionSearch.aspx

Comment: Retraction Watch launched its database: http://retractiondatabase.org/

Answer (score 3):

PubMed usually shows you whether an article has been retracted, corrected (errata), or has some comments.

[image: Retraction example]
[image: Erratum example]

(p.s. I don't have anything against Weinberg, it's just that I was doing some literature research and these two popped up among articles I had to cite. Clearly I won't cite the first one...)

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of many websites that operate across the spectrum of all of academia at once.  (This website is an exception!)  The closest thing I can think of is search engines like **google scholar**, which indeed could be of some use here.  In particular google scholar catches citations to articles more quickly than any "manual" service I know, so that whenever I find an article of interest to me I usually type it in to google and see what the internet turns up on it.

The other thing I can think of is that some academic fields have databases that carry, or purport to carry, bibliographic and review data for all articles that get published in that field.  For instance in mathematics there is [Math Reviews / MathSciNet](http://www.ams.org/mr-database) and [Zentralblatt](https://zbmath.org/). In CS there is [dblp](http://dblp.uni-trier.de/).  So e.g. in MathSciNet if an erratum is published on an article, then the erratum will be linked to the article and the written review will most often be modified to take the erratum into account.  The caveat is that individual, busy people have to do this so it may take some time, and the publisher will need to report the erratum in the right way in order for the bibliographic information to find its way to the database.

Answer (score 0):

All reputable journals will mention this on the website that matches the article in question. The other place to watch may be http://retractionwatch.com/ .

Comment: Thanks, the point of the question is to have one commonplace to perform the check, vs. going to the publisher's website.